# Where can I find the HTML5 <a href="attr:"> reference?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

So my question is mobile specific, because I need the "maps:" param's attributes for

Something like this:

```
<a href="maps:maybe+address+or+coords+here"></a>
```

It opens the Google Maps native apps on iPhone, but I want to send the address or coords of the place too.

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the **ll** (lat & long) parameter ... so something like:

```
<a href="maps:ll=38.870454,-77.055702">map</a>
```

You'll likely want a zoom as well ...

```
<a href="maps:ll=38.870454,-77.055702&z=10">map</a>
```

(Or something like that) more info on [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the maps url api here : http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Location

For example to open a pin at 51.5, -0.17 use this url :

```
http://maps.google.com/?ll=51.5,-0.17&q=Austrian%20Trade%20Commission,%20Princes%20Gate,%20London,%20United%20Kingdom
```