# How to open Google maps application using the "maps:" scheme?

Tags: iphone, html, google-maps

Firstly, I'm making a **web** application, not an iPhone application.

---

How do you open the Google maps application with a location passed to it so you can view it on the app?

I put this as a link:

```
<a href="maps:58.09423,67.97662">Open in Google Maps</a>
```

It does open the Google Maps application but it doesn't zoom into the place with a marker as requested, how do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185622/where-can-i-find-the-html5-a-href-attr-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html), I believe what you are looking for is:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=58.09423,67.97662">Open in Google Maps</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will open google maps with a marker on the requested location.

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=58.09423,67.97662"]]
```

Comment: Its the exact same link, it doesn't matter if it is a webapp or a native app.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer use the maps: protocol, just link directly to google. I believe maps: predates the phone, possibly a Symbian convention in origin.

Developer reference.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html