# Open Mobile Device's Maps When user Click Button

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile, maps

I am developing mobile application using phonegap. In my application, I have one button, which is "view location". When the user click on that button, device maps should be open and after the maps opened, and user click back, it should back to my application. How to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open maps application either with maps protocol or using maps.google.com / maps.apple.com (check this SO answer [How to open Google maps application using the "maps:" scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593244/how-to-open-google-maps-application-using-the-maps-scheme)).

But you can't return back to your application from maps application.

Probably only way to achieve this would be by using PhoneGap's ChildBrowser Plugin.

Comment: do you have any reference about how to use PhoneGap's ChildBrowser Plugin? Thanks

Comment: I've used it in one project, but I'm unable to post details. You just have to do some googling.